# Interact with Dropdown with a "nesty-input" class using Selenium that uses JSON

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate complaints with Tinder. I'm having trouble interacting with a dropdown box located at https://www.help.tinder.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=360000234452 . The element is the **"Tell use more"** dropdown box. I want to select "I want to request a refund".

I tried to use "find_element" but that does not work. Couldn't find any solution elsewhere to that's why I'm making this post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @briefings - If you wish to get an answer, please show us what you did. Show us some of your Selenium code, and show the HTML structure with the element that you wish to interact with